# Strange matrix multiplication behavior in Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I noticed strange behavior of some calculations in Matlab.

Matlab code listing:

```
% w_x, w_y, w_z are scalars
Q_0 = [0.788604; 0.41303067; 0.41303067; 0.192129]        % 4d vector
A = [ 0 -w_x -w_y -w_z; w_x 0 w_z -w_y; w_y -w_z 0 w_x; w_z w_y -w_x 0 ]       % 4x4 matrix
w = sqrt(w_x^2 + w_y^2 + w_z^2)        % scalar

Q_w1 = (cos(w*t/2.) + sin(w*t/2.) * 1./w * A ) * Q_0             % 4d vector
Q_w2 = (cos(w*t/2.) * Q_0+ (sin(w*t/2.) * 1./w * A)* Q_0 )       % 4d vector
```

I've got diffenet values of Q_w1 and Q_w2. Do theese sentenses equal in terms of math?  For me, it seems like they do. Is it just a Matlab bug?

Comment: @T.Bongers - that really shouldn't matter, but I'd guess the're elements of a rotation vector.

Comment: What are the values you get?

Comment: Yes, theese are components of a rotation vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have $+$ in the two lines, it's not doing the same thing in both places. Under the current definition, `cos(w*t/2.)` is a number, and the $+$ operator in the code

`Q_w1 = (cos(w*t/2.) + sin(w*t/2.) * 1./w * A ) * Q_0`

adds that real number to *every* element in the matrix on the right. The second code multiplies the matrix and vector beforehand, so the behaviour is different.

If you replace the first line of code with

`Q_w1 = (cos(w*t/2.)*eye(4) + sin(w*t/2.) * 1./w * A ) * Q_0`

then it gives the same output as line 2.

---

So the key difference is that adding a number to a matrix is not the same as adding the scalar times the *identity* matrix.

Note: I tested this in Octave, not Matlab - but AFAIK, they treat these the same.